# Why isn't this javascript running in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Critical issue - failed miserably to test in all of my browsers before deploying a live site... Best practices - shattered.

That point aside I have a fair amount of javascript running a site that I manage for the company I work for; the problem I am having is that Javascript is running in everything but I.E..

I've compared to some other issues already mentioned ( mostly here ) and I can't find anything relevant. Anyone's help would be marvelous; the site is at http://www.agpvideo.com

I am fairly sure that the problem exists somewhere in the following code...

Thanks ahead of time, and I hope that this gets me somewhere...

```
function ParseAjax(RootNode)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < RootNode.childNodes.length; i++ )
    {
        var Node = RootNode.childNodes[i];

        if( Node.nodeType == 3 || Node.nodeType == 8 )
        {
            continue;
        }
        else 
        {
            if( console && console.log )
                console.log("Parsing node: " + Node.nodeType + " :: " + Node.nodeName + " :: " + Node.className + " :: " + Node.id);

            var Ajax = null;        

            if(( Ajax = Node.getAttribute("ajax")) == null )
            {
                if( RootNode.childNodes[i].childNodes != null && RootNode.childNodes[i].childNodes.length > 0 )
                {
                    ParseAjax(RootNode.childNodes[i]);
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else
            {   
                if( Node.getAttribute("id") == null )
                {
                    document.writeln("Invalid AJAX callback. Please consult an administrator.");
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    var Img = document.createElement("img");
                    var Src = document.createAttribute("src");
                    Src.value = "resource/img/std/ajax-loader-0.gif";
                    Img.setAttribute("src", Src.value);
                    Node.appendChild(Img);

                    RequestAjax(Node.getAttribute("id"), Ajax);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


// JavaScript Document
function RequestAjax(ElementId,AjaxRequest)
{
    if( ElementId.length <= 0 )
    {
        return;
    }
    else if( AjaxRequest.length <= 0 )
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if( console && console.log )
            console.log("Preparing AJAX request...");

        var Request = null;

        if( window.XMLHttpRequest )
        {
            Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            Request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        Request.ElementId = ElementId;
        Request.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if( console && console.log )
            {
                if( Request.readyState <= 1)
                    console.log("AJAX state change: " + Request.readyState);
                else
                    console.log("AJAX state change: " + Request.readyState + "/" + Request.status);
            }

            if( Request.readyState == 4 && Request.status == 200 )
            {
                var TargetElement = null;
                if(( TargetElement = document.getElementById(Request.ElementId)) == null )
                {
                    if( console && console.log )
                        console.log("AJAX TargetElement is null. Cannot set content for " + Request.ElementId);
                }
                else
                {
                    TargetElement.innerHTML = Request.responseText;

                    ParseAjax(TargetElement);
                }
            }
        }

        Request.open("GET",AjaxRequest,true);
        Request.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: Find where is the problem and put here the relevant code, we're not a remote debugging service.

Comment: And you're rude? Edits coming.

Comment: That wasn't rude, that was truth.

Comment: It was a little rude. A clearly distraught individual panicking ( granted over my own mistakes ) over an issue that can be solved in two clicks and a button press by a qualified individual shouldn't warrant 'Hey you're dumb, don't make step out of my box.' IMO.

Comment: But thanks Everyone for your marvelous comments and suggestions...

Comment: @DigitalJedi805: to avoid this don't post an incomplete question next time. Your time constraints are yours to deal with, not ours, the help you'll get here is entirely voluntary. If you want fast help, you need to provide all the information up-front and not ask a bunch of strangers to debug your whole site - which your initial question did.

Comment: @Mat - I didn't ask anyone to debug my site. I asked someone to tell me why my code was breaking in IE - and specified where I believed the error was, with code. I referenced the site in case there was a necessity to see results in the actual execution environment. The answer to the question could be determined from what I posted, so in reality the comment is unnecessary, degrading, and truly unhelpful. And it's even further degrading to see the comment get bumped up simply because so many SO users have inflamed egos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check the existence of console as

```
if(window.console)
{
}
```

or

```
if(typeof console !== "undefined")
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Highly valid information in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple `console.log` statements in your JavaScript code which IE won't run unless the console is open. Comment them out or remove them.

Comment: Even checking first for existence of the console?

Comment: If you're checking for the existence of console then either you're doing it wrong or it's broken because it's the console.log lines that are killing your page in IE.

Comment: Looks like checking for existence of the console itself was stopping me. Thank you.